# How to code a macro that extracts numerics values from a range, do differents operations like sum and multiplications

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone I hope you're doing fine.

This is my 1st request here in the forum, as I didn't have the chance to find what I'm looking for, I've been searching for this for months but didn't get lucky, and I couldn't figure out how to code it since I'm a beginner.

So basically I have these multiple Excel files that contain columns (`long`,`latitude`,`altitude`, `containers`,`spill`, and `volume` of non contained garbage)

The problem is in the container range, it contains the number of container(num) and the type of container(char) and the volume of the container ( num) separated by "/" character and if we have more than a container in one place we put + sign then number of the second container, type, volume, separated also by "/"

What I'm really looking to do is to sum the number of container and multiply it by the sum of volumes for each cell and then add it to the spill if there is any and then output it in a total column

If there is one type of container then there is no need to do a sum , only multiplication and then add the spill value then output it to the total column

And I'm counting to use "/" sign and + sign as a wildcards to extract the numeric values if this possible

For the volume column there is no math required, only copy paste to the total column.

I apologize for the bad English, you can leave a comment in case it's hard to understand, and I'm looking forward to your help.

Example:
[image]

Another example:
[image]

Comment: [SO is not a code writing service](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it is for specific issues arising from your code. Please edit in your attempt and the issue or error you are getting. Otherwise this will get closed pretty quick.

Comment: @Warcupine hi i apologize for the inconvenience, but i was hoping to get some guidlines to do the code, any hint or so would me much appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really the place for general suggestions. Start on one aspect of what you are trying to do, give it an attempt, if you can't get it to work come back with a more specific issue. Rinse and repeat until the whole thing does what you want.

Comment: What is the result of the calculation for row 29 2/FUT/p/50+1/FUT/m/100 ? Is 1/BP/p/120+FUT/p/50
on row 34 correct, there is no 2nd container number ?

Comment: @CDP1802 for that row it should be a 1 number its an error, but in overall, everytime there is plus sign there should be a sum of the 1st two numbers and a multiplication by the sum of two last numbers

Comment: So 1+2=3 multiply 50+100 = 450 ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes exactly and if there any value on the debord range, then the total is equal to the sum of 450 and the debord ( spill)

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi , i really appreciate your help , thank you for real , what i'm looking for is a macro that do it for all the cells in between ranges from BAC to VOLUME , and then create an adjacent range of total and put the result there

Comment: @CDP1802 im thinking like this :
sub calcul_total()
dim a as integer, b as integer, c as integer
    for each cell in range("E")

Comment: @CDP1802
for each cell in range("E:G")
           a=left(isnumeric,,"/")              'an instruction to retrieve the numbers at the beginning from each cell that is located before / sign
           b=right(isnumeric,,"/")            ' also an instruction to retrive the numbers after the "/" sign 
         C=find("+")
          if    C.value = "+" then        ' find if there is a + sign
           ' if there is a + sign do the sum of A and the value after the sign
          end if

Comment: @CDP1802
and then multiply the sum by the value after the / sign 
then check the value of debord if its not empty then add it the previous result 

cell ( rowCount, 8 that stands for columnH ) = total.value

Comment: In row 8 for example, in the Volume column (cell G8) put the formulae =CalcVolume(E8) and in the Total columns (cell H8) put =F8+G8 to add debord to volume to get total. Copy to other rows as required. See [split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) and [using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a User Defined Function with the code located in a module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function CalcVolume(s As String) As Variant

    Dim ar1 As Variant, ar2 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, num As Double, vol As Double, bError As Boolean
    bError = False

    ' split into array
    ar1 = Split(s, "+")
    For i = LBound(ar1) To UBound(ar1)
        ar2 = Split(ar1(i), "/")
        If UBound(ar2) = 3 And IsNumeric(ar2(0)) And IsNumeric(ar2(3)) Then
            num = num + ar2(0)
            vol = vol + ar2(3)
        Else
            bError = True
        End If
    Next

    If bError = False Then
        CalcVolume = vol * num
    Else
        CalcVolume = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If

End Function

Sub test()
   Debug.Print CalcVolume("2/FUT/p/50+1/FUT/m/100")
End Sub
```